# I need help with finding the answer for k when given two points on a logarithmic function

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, logarithms

A point on a graph is $(1/8, -3)$ of the logarithmic function $f (x)=\log b^x$, and the point $(4, k)$ is on the graph of the inverse, $y=f^{-1}(x)$.Determine the value $k$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

$y=\log_bx, -3=\log_b\frac{1}{8},b=2$
$f(x)=\log_2x, f^{-1}(x)=2^x, f^{-1}(4)=?$

Comment: So therefore, the value of k is 16, because f^-1(4)= 2^4 which equals 16, right?

Comment: @Rosey this answer is for $f(x)=\log_b x$. but in your question it is $\log b^x$ so which one is the case?

Comment: @Rosey you are right:-)